# Placing elements within a container div into an array - jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a div that contains a number of Instagram images, produced by the instafeed.js plugin. After running the plugin, the resultant HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="instafeed">
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
    etc...
</div>
```

I am trying to find a way to load the contents of this div into an array; I believe that the easiest way would be to just take the  tags, which is fine.

I'm pretty inexperienced with both JS and jQuery, which is why I'm having difficulty achieving this and I've not been able to find any forum posts that quite do what I'm hoping to achieve.

So far, all I'm trying to do is load the contents of the div into an array and print it back out to the document, which should (in my mind anyway) add the  tags back into the HTML. I'm trying with both JavaScript and jQuery and having little success with either. I'd appreciate any thoughts:

JS:

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementById('instafeed');
var pics = containerDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');

console.log(pics); //Tells me at least that I have an array of img

for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
    document.write(pics[i]);
} //Seemingly does nothing
```

jQuery:
(I'm really sorry if this code is just all wrong, I really don't know jQuery very well at all)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pics = [];

    $('#instafeed').find('img').each(function() {
        pics.push($(this));
    });

    for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
        console.log(pics[i]);
    }

});
```

Any thoughts, tips or pointers would be much appreciated.

Edit:
Just to add a little background to my problem, to avoid causing any more confusion.

I'm trying to pull four random images from a user-specific Instagram feed for display on a website. instafeed.js can pull just four images and it can randomise the images, but Instagram itself always sends the four most recent images, so the plugin is just randomising the order of the same four pictures each time.

I'm trying to let the plugin send through every picture, which will go into the div instafeed. From here I want to load all of the contained images into an array so that I can randomly pick four images for display on the site.

Comment: What do you mean by _load the contents of this div into an array;_?

Comment: `$('#instafeed').find('img')` gives you an array anyway, why then put them into another array?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the links?

Comment: I've added some extra info above in an edit.

Comment: If the service returns most recent images, there is no task you can do to retrieve more pictures. Try to retrieve more than most recent images and randomize it it's a  child-play.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do - I am pulling in all of the images, which the plugin populates within the div, but I have no control over how many are output, which is why I want to take all of the images into an array so that I can control how I output from that.

Comment: I believe you are using instafeed.js library to get the images from instafeed. if yes, why don't try with instafeed success callback to put all those images into array and do whatever you want to do with those array of images.

Ref : http://instafeedjs.com/#advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery code that you write is correct. Only you need the div where you need to put the images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var pics = [];

   $('#instafeed').find('img').each(function() {
      pics.push($(this));
   });

   for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
      $('div#yourDiv').append(pics[i]);
   }
```

});

See the line of the `for()`

You can extract only the SRC of the images and then make like you want

```
   $('#instafeed').find('img').each(function() {
      pics.push($(this).attr('src'));
   });
   console.log(pics); // returns an array of src.
```

Comment: Why not just do `$('#instafeed').find('img').each(function() { $('div#yourDiv').append($(this));  });` instead of having the extra loop?

Comment: Maybe he wants to make in other moment and not instantly.

Comment: in which case I would just do `var pics = $('#instafeed').find('img');` then later OP can use `pics.each` - just one loop, better on performance

Comment: I answer that he asked. Otherwise, OP doesn't explain what he needs exactly yet.

Comment: I've added some extra info above in an edit. What I really want is an array of images from which I can pull out a random selection. In trying to make sure I'm doing it right, I just want to be able to dump the contents of my array into the page, so that I know my array holds what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who has tried to help me along with this. It turns out that the problem I was having stemmed from my query attempting to run before instafeed.js had been able to pull the images through from Instagram, and so there was nothing for it to find in the div. I've managed to fix this with a setTimeout.

For anyone who is interested, and just in case anyone else might come across this in future with a similar problem, here is my complete code (it's a little inelegant I'm sure, but I'm still a relative novice at JS.)

```
function snagImages() {
    var pics = [];

    $('div#instafeed').find('img').each(function() {
        pics.push($(this).attr('src'));
    });

    reduceGallery(4, pics);
}

function reduceGallery(limit, pics) {
    if (limit === undefined) {
        limit = 4;
    }

    var gallery = [];

    while (gallery.length < limit) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length);

        if ( gallery.indexOf(pics[j]) > -1) {
            continue;
        } 

        gallery.push(pics[j]);
    }

    displayPics(gallery);
}

function displayPics(gallery) {
    for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('gallery').innerHTML += '<a href="' + gallery[i] + '" title="Gallery Image">' + '<img src="' + gallery[i] + '" alt="Gallery Image" />' + '</a>';
    }
}

var userFeed = new Instafeed( {
    options
});
userFeed.run();

setTimeout(function() { snagImages() }, 500);
```